# Treat subfolder in URL as domain

Tags: nginx

I'm setting up a new VPS with nginx. I can't edit my hosts file on this PC, but I'd still like to set up websites and test them as if they were on my domains. My server is reachable at an IP address (let's say it's 1.1.1.1). Is it possible to set nginx up so that it treats 1.1.1.1/domain.com as if it were domain.com? If so, how?

Maybe I'm overthinking this, maybe I shouldn't be doing this. Feel free to tell me.

Comment: Why do you need to change hosts on VPS? You need to change it on your computer.

Comment: That's what I meant. I can't change the hosts file on my PC (so as to override the DNS).

Answer (score 0):

If editing DNS is not an option, then you could listen on different ports for each website.

```
server {
    listen  8001;
    root    /var/www/domain1.com;
    # ...
}

server {
    listen  8002;
    root    /var/www/domain2.com;
    # ...
}

server {
    listen  8003;
    root    /var/www/domain3.com;
    # ...
}
```

Then each website would have it's own document root:

```
http://1.1.1.1:8001
http://1.1.1.1:8002
http://1.1.1.1:8003
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @putnamhill. This would work, since I would just have to alter the vhosts a bit before actually switching the DNS. However, this is me trying to do something for my office where the network is kind of locked down and uncommon ports (to regular office cats) are not allowed. I can't even use an FTP client here :)

Comment: Do you have any ssh access? If so maybe you could do something with port forwarding e.g. `ssh -L 8001:1.1.1.1:8001 you@1.1.1.1` Then access with `http://localhost:8001`.

Comment: Hi @putnamhill, again thanks for your input. My question is more about letting a webserver (and the web applications I run on it) think that it's getting a request for a domain when I'm actually requesting and IP. This way, I could install WordPress, for instance, set everything up (migrate content and whatnot) and then switch over the DNS. I've given up on it, by now :).